# How do I export schema after upgrading Hibernate to 5.4.1?

Tags: java, hibernate, schemaexport

I've recently updated Hibernate from 4.3.7 to 5.4.1 and the `SchemaExport` API has changed since 5.1. This code now shows compilation problems (on `SchemaExport` constructor and `execute` method).

```
/**
 * Method to generate a SQL script which aim is to create SQL tables for the
 * entities indicated as parameters.
 */
private void generateScript(Class<?>... classes) {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, entityManagerFactory.getProperties().get(DIALECT_PROPERTY).toString());
    for (Class<?> entityClass : classes) {
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(entityClass);
    }
    SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(configuration);
    schemaExport.setDelimiter(SCRIPT_DELIMITER);
    schemaExport.setOutputFile(getScriptPath());
    schemaExport.setFormat(true);
    boolean consolePrint = false;
    boolean exportInDatabase = false;
    schemaExport.execute(consolePrint, exportInDatabase, false, true);
}
```

I've seen other questions related to this problem, but nothnig specific enough to help me rewrite this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've done and it works :

```
private void genererScript(Class<?>... classes) {

    StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySetting(Environment.DIALECT, entityManagerFactory.getProperties().get(DIALECT_PROPERTY).toString())
            .build();

    MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources( standardRegistry );
    for (Class<?> entityClass : classes) {
        sources.addAnnotatedClass(entityClass);
    }

    MetadataImplementor metadata = (MetadataImplementor) sources
            .getMetadataBuilder()
            .build();

    EnumSet<TargetType> targetTypes = EnumSet.of(TargetType.SCRIPT);

    try {
        Files.delete(Paths.get(getScriptPath()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        /*
         * The file did not exist...
         * we do nothing.
         */
    }

    SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
    schemaExport.setDelimiter(SCRIPT_DELIMITER);
    schemaExport.setOutputFile(getScriptPath());
    schemaExport.setFormat(true);
    schemaExport.createOnly(targetTypes, metadata);
}
```